# Подскажите, как можно вызвать функцию по скролу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

У меня есть функция

```
(function($) {
  function generateBarGraph(wrapper) {
    // Set Up Values Array
    var values = [];

    // Get Values and save to Array
    $(wrapper + ' .bar, .bar2, .bar3').each(function(index, el) {
      values.push($(this).data('value'));
    });

    // Get Max Value From Array`введите сюда код`
    var max_value = Math.max.apply(Math, values);

    // Set width of bar to percent of max value
    $(wrapper + ' .bar, .bar2, .bar3').each(function(index, el) {
      var bar = $(this),
          value = bar.data('value'),
          percent = Math.ceil((value / max_value) * 100);

      // Set Width & Add Class
      bar.width(percent + '%');
      bar.addClass('in');
    });
  }

      // Generate the bar graph on window load...
  $( window ).scroll(function(wrapper) {
    generateBarGraph('#dashboard-stats');
  });
})(jQuery); // Fully reference jQuery after this point.
```

Она загружается сразу когда обновляешь страницу, а мне нужно что бы анимация происходила только когда когда я проскролю до блока с `#dashboard-stats`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определяем скролл экрана + его высоту и проверяем чтобы это было меньше позиции требуемого элемента. Так же чтобы предотвратить многочисленный вызов сетаем, что он был вызван.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#dashboard-stats').offset().top &&
    !$('#dashboard-stats').data('triggered')) {
    $('#dashboard-stats').data('triggered', true);
    generateBarGraph('#dashboard-stats');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $('#dashboard-stats').offset().top) {
    $('#dashboard-stats').data('triggered', false);
  }
});

function generateBarGraph(selector) {
  console.log('triggered');
}
```

```css
.block {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#dashboard-stats {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
<div id="dashboard-stats"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: сейчас попробую, а скажите пожалуйста библиотека должна быть именно 2.1.1?

Comment: @СергійЧуйко нет

Comment: не то, не работает, я добавил 
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#dashboard-stats').offset().top &&
    !$('#dashboard-stats').data('triggered')) {
    $('#dashboard-stats').data('triggered', true);
    generateBarGraph('#dashboard-stats');
  }
});

вместо

Comment: $( window ).scroll(function(wrapper) {
    generateBarGraph('#dashboard-stats');
  });
})(jQuery);

и ничего(

Comment: https://full-house.in.ua/radiators/vertical

Comment: вот мой сайт, если проскролить в низ там есть диаграмма, там происходит анимация, но она сразу происходить когда загружается страница, а мне нужно что бы анимация была только тогда когда я проскроллю до него)

Comment: @СергійЧуйко да сами посмотрите вместо чего вы вставили. Ничего не смущает в конце?! В консоли не крошится ничего?!

Comment: спасибо) посмотрел более внимательней))

Comment: а такой вопрос) 
теперь мне нужно сделать что бы когда я скролил вверх) а потом обратно в низ) функция снов срабатывала) можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: @СергійЧуйко обновился.

Comment: что то снова не выходит) функция работает, когда скролишь все хорошо, но когда подымаешь вверх, и снова скролишь в низ до блока, анимация заново не срабатывает) 
что то мне кажется нужно писать функцию которая будит отменять функцию если блок не в видимости екрана)

Comment: @СергійЧуйко скорее всего это анимация тех элементов повторно не работает.

Comment: возможно, буду разбирать)) спасибо за помощь)) 

Если сможете подсказать как сделать из той функции которую я скидывал, что бы она повторно работала) буду только рад)

Comment: @СергійЧуйко как вариант обнулите и задайте заново.

Comment: спасибо)) но эту функцию скорей всего нельзя обнулить) или разве что задавать интервал или сеттаймаут)) но я уже не столь силен  в этом)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if($('elem').length > 0 && $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('elem').offset().top){                                                                   
        $('elem').fadeIn();                                    
}
```